# Why new envonments of anaconda are empty

Tags: environment, conda

I am using conda version `4.9.2` in ubuntu `18.04`. I firstly create a new environment and then try to install a package but surprisingly this package already exists but there but when I try o import it in my jupyter notebook, I face the following error:

```
ImportError: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea why this package exist there. When I look for it, it is in the following folder:

```
/home/My_UBU/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

When I create any new environment (`conda create --name my_env`), if I check `envs` of my `miniconda3`, it has only one folder named `conda-meta` which has also one file named `history`. Installed packages are going somewhere else rather than my environment. I do appreciate any help to solve my issue with conda in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you've activated your conda environment?

try the command

```
conda env list
```

to see what environments you have created on your machine.

The name of the environment is in the first column, and the path where the environment is maintained in the last column.

There should be an asterisk next to your default conda environment.

Take a look at your lists and activate the environment from the command line substituting your chosen environment name

```
conda activate my_env
```

Once your environment is set, you should be able to issue all the commands you need to maintain it.

Edited:
If you want to create a new enviroment and install packages in one shot try something like this

```
conda create --name  py310 -c anaconda python
```

This would create the new environment **py310** and install the latest available python and its packages meant to work together from the **anaconda** channel.

Comment: Yes, but why does the environment in the envs  folder contain a single folder 'conda-meta' which has also one file named history. I.e. where are the environments packages.

Comment: You would need to follow up with **conda install ** commands.  You can also access a bit of short help just by entering **conda** to see what's possible in your virtual environment.  The empty envs folder means that you haven't installed any packages to work with.

Comment: For example, if you wanted to work with **numpy** a great package for arrays and scientific applications, you'd then run **conda install -c anaconda numpy**     Anaconda shows the exact commands for numpy at https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numpy

Comment: Anaconda.org has a long list of supported packages that you can try with a bit of documentation on each:  https://anaconda.org/anaconda