# How to install Anacoda Navigator on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: python3, 21.04, anaconda

I have shifted from Windows 10 yesterday and I wanted to install Anaconda Navigator as I am just gonna began my programming journey from python, Please guide me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the x86_64 architecture, you can download Anaconda from here and get started:

```
https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Jupyter lab   and Spyder are good tools to work with python programming and data.  Both can be installed from the Anaconda Navigator (recommended).

It's a good idea to create anaconda environments and maintain different areas like projects to keep development efforts with different tools clean and separate.

Please take care to make sure you have the anaconda environments set up correctly:

[Why new envonments of anaconda are empty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348511/why-new-envonments-of-anaconda-are-empty/1348623#1348623)